# Remote Desktop Farm Deployment ports

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, remote-desktop-services

I'm in an environment where the firewall is very strict (as in every port is closed unless requested to be opened).

When deploying my 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Farm through PowerShell I'm getting to the point where I am making the Session Host server a member of a Farm using this code:

```
##Imports Remote Desktop Services Module to enable config of RDS
Import-Module RemoteDesktopServices

##Configures Remote Desktop Server to be a member of a Farm
cd RDS:\RDSConfiguration\ConnectionBrokerSettings
$IP = dir -Path RDS:\RDSConfiguration\ConnectionBrokerSettings\RedirectableAddresses
Set-Item ServerPurpose -value 3 -ConnectionBroker "BROKER-Server" -FarmName "FARM NAME" -IPAddressRedirection 1 -CurrentRedirectableAddresses $IP.name
```

When running this is get an error stating that access is denied. 
If I open up all TCP Ports to the Broker it works, so I'm wondering if anyone knows which ports its using. I have done some research and found this article:     http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16164.which-ports-are-used-by-a-rds-2012-deployment.aspx I know this is for 2012 R2 but I cant find anything for 2008 R2. I've opened these ports and it still doesn't work, so I must be missing something.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated....

Cheers,

Chris